# Extracting plotly.express selection in JupyterLab

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab, plotly-python

I want to extract the indices or a mask from a selection made in a plotly.express figure. The figure is created in JupyterLab.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species")
fig.show()
```

This figure shows the untouched figure.
[image]

This figure show a arbitrary selection. From this selection, I would like to extract a list of indices or a boolean mask, or anything that will allow the selection to be extracted from the original DataFrame.
[image]

There seems to be some attributes/functions that are to aid with this, such as fig.data[0].selectedpoints. I am unable to utilize them.

plotly is version: '4.14.3'

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there is no way to get the range selected by the user. The feature you pointed out in your question, `selectedpoints`, is there for graphers to use to highlight specific ranges. It can be used as a scenario for the creator rather than a user choice. I have customized this feature with information from [this page](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Eempet/14976/how-to-select-and-highlight-poi/#/).

```
import  plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

df = px.data.iris()

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['sepal_width'],
                         y=df['sepal_length'],
                         mode='markers',
                         marker=dict(color='rgba(0, 45, 240)', size=10)))

fig.update_layout(width=600, 
              height=550, 
              autosize=False,
              xaxis=dict(zeroline=False),
              hovermode='closest')

fig.show()
```

[image]

```
inds = [15+k for k in range(30)]
fig.data[0].update(selectedpoints=inds,
                   selected=dict(marker=dict(color='red')),#color of selected points
                   unselected=dict(marker=dict(color='rgb(200,200, 200)',#color of unselected pts
                                   opacity=0.9)));
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and on clarifying the use of 'selectedpoint'. I think that  elaborating on its use is superfluous in the context of the question, nonetheless I appreciate learning its uses.